# Using if statements inside while loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a vending machine problem where the user is offered 3 choices :

1. water 2. cola 3. gatorade

   water = $1.00 , cola = $1.50 , gatorade = $2.00

After taking inputs of quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies from the user , I calculate the total amount in dollars. Now I need to check whether the total amount is sufficient for each of the 3 choices of drinks. If the amount is lesser than the cost, I need to prompt the user to try again, if it is greater then I need to display a message for thee user's change amount. I believe this needs while loop and if, elif, else statements. Below is my program so far :

```
import sys 
print('You have three drinks to choose from this Vending Machine: \n 1. Water \n 2. Cola \n 3. Gatorade')
water = 1.00
cola = 1.50
gatorade = 2.00
choice = 0
while not choice:
  try:
    choice = int(input('Please select any one of the three choices of drinks (1,2 or 3) from the list above'))
    if choice not in (1,2,3):
        raise ValueError
  except ValueError:
    choice = 0
    print("That is not a valid choice ! Try again")
if choice == 1:
   print("1. water = $1.00")
elif choice == 2:
   print("2. cola = $1.50")
elif choice == 3:
   print("3. gatorade = $2.00")

qrt = int(input("How many quarters did you insert ?"))
dm = int(input("How many dimes did you insert ?"))
nk = int(input("How many nickels did you insert ?"))
pn = int(input("How many pennies did you insert ?"))

total = qrt/4 + dm/10 + nk/20 + pn/100
```

Now, I need to check if the total amount (that the user inserted) is greater or lesser than the cost of the drink he selected.

If greater I need to return change (display message for change amount).

If lesser then I need to prompt the user to try inserting coins again.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Because it looks good to me!

Comment: I need to check if the total amount (that the user inserted) is greater or lesser than the cost of the drink he selected. If greater I need to return change (display message for change amount) , if lesser then I need to prompt the user to try inserting coins again. How can I do that ?

Comment: By total amount you mean the `total`, that you are calculating at the end of your code? and you want the user to re-insert only coins, not everything?

Comment: Yes that is the total I mean, the one that I am calculating at the end. And I want the user to insert quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies again if the total is lesser than the cost.

Comment: Check the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need to do. Also take the logic and modify the code as per your requirement.

Don't just copy it. Hope it helps.

```
import sys 
print('You have three drinks to choose from this Vending Machine: \n 1. Water \n 2. Cola \n 3. Gatorade')
water = 1.00
cola = 1.50
gatorade = 2.00
choice = 0
while not choice:
    try:
        choice = int(input('Please select any one of the three choices of drinks (1,2 or 3) from the list above: '))
        if choice not in (1,2,3):
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        choice = 0
        print("That is not a valid choice ! Try again")

if choice == 1:
    print("1. water = $1.00")
    total_to_be = 1.00
elif choice == 2:
    print("2. cola = $1.50")
    total_to_be = 1.50
elif choice == 3:
    print("3. gatorade = $2.00")
    total_to_be = 2.00

qrt = int(input("How many quarters did you insert ?"))
dm = int(input("How many dimes did you insert ?"))
nk = int(input("How many nickels did you insert ?"))
pn = int(input("How many pennies did you insert ?"))

total = qrt/4 + dm/10 + nk/20 + pn/100

# total = round(total, 2)

while total != total_to_be: 

    if total >= total_to_be:
        print(total)
        break

    else:
        print("======================= Please try Again ================================")
        qrt = int(input("How many quarters did you insert ?"))
        dm = int(input("How many dimes did you insert ?"))
        nk = int(input("How many nickels did you insert ?"))
        pn = int(input("How many pennies did you insert ?"))

        total = qrt/4 + dm/10 + nk/20 + pn/100
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help bro... I made some modifications acc to the question.. Since we need to return change , I returned total - total_to_be. It works like a charm ! That last while loop was the key.

Comment: @SiddharthSingh glad, could help! Cheers!